# How to initialze the return value of a function before calling it in main()?

Tags: c

I need to initialize the return value of a function before calling it in `main()`.

I did it by first passing the arguments of the function with an impossible conditions like

```
 int func(int x, int y)
 {
     if (x == 0 && y == 0)
         return 10; // the value I want to initialize the function to
                    // after making sure x and y will never equal to zero
     else 
     {
         // do whatever
     }
 }
```

But I think there's a better way to do this.

I have tried to use the indirection operator (`*`) since the function name itself is a pointer by using this statement `*func = 10;`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not really clear on what you're trying to achieve. Why not just `return 10;`? This looks like an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: `return 10` doesn't initialize anything. This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe the actual problem that you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

The question is not very clear but I think you are asking for:

```
int func(int x, int y)
{
     int retval = 0;

     if ( x == 0 && y == 0 )
          retval = 10;

     // ...other stuff...

     return retval;
}
```

Some languages have an implicit variable for the return value that you can modify but C does not .

There is no such thing as "initialize the return value before calling the function" , the return value is part of the function execution .